# Replacing Part of a String in Access Query - Wildcard Characters

Tags: regex, ms-access

I have an old hyperlink field that was never linked to the correct path.  The field still has relevance though in that it contains the filename associated with the record.  I'm trying to update this field by removing the path and leaving just the filename.  Hyperlink functionality is not needed.

I've already converted the field to text and removed the hashes so all that remains is the incomplete filepath string.  The paths are all similar in format but vary in foldername\filename.

`"FOLDERNAME\FILENAME.tif"`

In example: `"RESEARCH LAB 22\RESEARCH LAB 22 001.tif"`

I have the following query, but it requires replacing the foldername manually.

`UPDATE BAT1_Document SET BAT1_Document.HYPERLINK = Replace([Hyperlink],"RESEARCH LAB 22\","");`

Replacing `"*\"` with `""` would cover my needs but my understanding is that wildcard characters can't be used in a Replace update query so I am at a loss as to how to implement this.

Comment: You can find and replace wildcard character. Refer to [Find Wildcard in Access](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/find-wildcard-characters-in-an-access-database-HA001171536.aspx)

Comment: That is what I originally tried but the replace part doesn't except wildcards.  Finding `*\*.tif` finds records correctly, but I need to replace it with `*.tif` which does not work as all records are replaced with "*.tif", not the string that precedes the file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are allways "FOLDERNAME\FILENAME.tif" then try:

```
UPDATE BAT1_Document SET BAT1_Document.HYPERLINK = mid([Hyperlink],instr(1,[Hyperlink],"\")+1);
```